# Oracle Pivot the rows into columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table A with the following records.

```
 Use_code | SITE_NUM | rep_name
 BILL_TO       119     abc
 SHIP_TO       119     xyz
 BILL_TO       120     jkf
 SHIP_TO       121     nir
```

I need to update a table B like below. For each `SITE_NUM` we need to update BILL_TO and SHIP_TO records rep_name's under different columns like below.

```
 SITE_NUM | BILL_TO_REP_NAME | SHIP_TO_REP_NAME
 119      | abc              | xyz
 120      | jkf              | null
 121      | nul              | nir
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to generate the results:

```
select a.site_num,
       max(case when a.use_code = 'BILL_TO' then rep_name end) as bill_to,
       max(case when a.use_code = 'BILL_FROM' then rep_name end) as bill_from
from a
group by a.site_num;
```

To update the rows using this information, you can use `merge`.  It is not obvious if you really need an `update`, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the best solution, but this is the first thing that crossed my mind, and if nobody comes with a better solution, you could try to do something like this:

```
SELECT s.SITE_NUM, b.REP_NAME AS BILL_TO_REP_NAME, 
       sh.REP_NAME AS SHIP_TO_REP_NAME
FROM (SELECT SITE_NUM
     FROM tblA
     GROUP BY SITE_NUM) s
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT SITE_NUM, rep_name
                FROM tblA
                WHERE Use_code = 'BILL_TO') b ON s.SITE_NUM = b.SITE_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT SITE_NUM, rep_name
                FROM tblA
                WHERE Use_code = 'SHIP_TO') sh ON s.SITE_NUM = sh.SITE_NUM
ORDER BY s.SITE_NUM;
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/17147/5) to see how it's work... I'm little rusty with database but think this will do the job.